# Ajax json post is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I need to pass a json data to the controller. hence i have created a ajax post. But it is not calling the action method.

```
function DeleteRow(postData) {
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("DeleteGridRow","Project")',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    async: false,
    data: JSON.stringify(postData),
    success: function (data) {

    }
});
```

}

My Actionmethod

```
 [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult DeleteGridRow(string postData)
    {
        return Json(null);
    }
```

Please help

Comment: did you run fiddler or similar tool to make sure you are send a POST and not a GET call?

Comment: Mark, Thanks for your reply. I have used firebug, in post i could see the value i'm sending. but the response is empty. Overall the error it is showing in firebug is "500: internal server error"

Comment: 1. using [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) for debug 2. add error function error:function(error){} 3. Test your url for result.

Comment: Can you verify that the URL indeed exists, or throw a debugger on your solution at the call to that method to make sure its actually getting called.

Comment: Thanks brian_wang & mark. Your inputs was really valuable. actually my url.action was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have separated your javascript file from your cshtml or vbhtml page, then this is not going to work. Your URL would be interpreted wrongly. You should pass URL where you are submitting to your function DeleteRow. Something like this:

```
$("#myForm").submit(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr("action");
    var data = Use your method to collect data or $(this).serialize();

    DeleteRow(url, data);
});

function DeleteRow(url, postData) {  
    $.ajax({  
        url: url,  
        type: 'POST',  
        dataType: "json",  
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
        async: false,  
        data: JSON.stringify(postData),  
        success: function (data) {  

    }  
});
```

Something like this should work.

Comment: You should visit your previous questions and mark as answer those answers that helped you, otherwise you might not get response to your question. :-) Regards